# Increasing number in Six digit

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\ x_1\ x_2\ x_3\ x_4\ x_5\ x_6$ be a six digit number, find the number of such numbers.

Case 1) $\ x_1 <\ x_2 <\ x_3 <\ x_4 <\ x_5<\ x_6$

Case 2) $\ x_1 <\ x_2 <\ x_3 $=$\ x_4 <\ x_5<\ x_6$

Case 3) $\ x_1 <\ x_2 <\ x_3 $ $\le$ $\ x_4 <\ x_5<\ x_6$

I have no idea how to approach this problem ,

Comment: Least number is 123456 and the greatest is 456789

Comment: Hint: For case $(1)$, try ${9\choose 6}$. Why does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider choosing $6$ distinct digits from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

- **case 1**: The 6 chosen digits can be arranged in only one order. Hence the answer is $\binom{9}{6}$
- **case 2**: we need to choose only $5$ digits as $2$ of $6$ are equal. So the answer is $\binom{9}{5}$
- **case 3**: It is the union of the above cases.

Comment: I want you to approve my understanding ,we select six number from 9 number. That is the combination part and now for increasing number among the  selected number their is one way to arrange the nunber that is the permutation part. Now i understood the logic behind it

Comment: @Samar yeah that's exactly what we are doing here!